# Pass NET-Object to parallel function (parfeval) in Matab

Tags: .net, matlab, parallel-processing, twincat-ads

I am trying to pass a NET-Object to a function running on a parallel pool in Matlab.

While I thought "parallel.pool.Constant" is the way to do it - as it works fine for other objects (like database connection) - it doesn't work in this case.

As I don't receive an error message, I can't find out why it won't work.

Also the display function doesn't show anything.

**Sample-Code:**

```
%% Import Ads.dll
AdsAssembly = NET.addAssembly('D:\TwinCat3\AdsApi\.NET\v4.0.30319\TwinCAT.Ads.dll');
import TwinCAT.Ads.*;

%Create TcAdsClient instance
tcClient = TcAdsClient;

tc = parallel.pool.Constant(tcClient); %Create pool constant to pass object

pool = gcp();
parfeval(pool,@pfcn,0,tc);

function pfcn(tc)

    disp(tc.Value);
    tcClient = tc.Value;
    tcClient.Connect(851); %Connect to ADS port 851 on the local machine

end
```

An example where it works fine for me (OPC UA Client):

```
pool = gcp();

Q = parallel.pool.DataQueue;

serverList = opcuaserverinfo('192.168.60.200'); 
hsInfo = findDescription(serverList, 'K6');

uaClient = opcua(hsInfo);

opc_const = parallel.pool.Constant(uaClient);

parfeval(pool, @pfcn, 0, Q, opc_const);

listener = afterEach(Q, @disp);

function pfcn(Q, opc_const)

    par_uaClient = opc_const.Value;
    connect(par_uaClient);
    conn_state = isConnected(par_uaClient);
    send(Q, par_uaClient)

end
```